# jQuery Validate odd error when custom messages are specified

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form for creating product records which has (user controlled) dynamic entries (i.e. a product can have N options (such as different colours, or different finishes etc, which may also have different prices). The user adds a set of fields for each option as necessary. Of course most products will have only one version (and therefore only one option), so in this case it is not necessary to supply an option name, just a price. So the option name fields are only validated if there is more than one option price field on the form.

```
    $('.iprice').each(function() {
      $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        number: true,
    */    messages : { required:'enter price', number:'enter only price' }  */
      });
    });
      $('.iname').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
          required: function(){
            if ($('[name="attr[2][price]"]').length) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
          },
    /*      messages: function(){
              if ($('[name="attr[2][price]"]').length) {
                return 'option name?';
              }
            }  */
          });
       });
```

The Validation works fine as described above. (see the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/e4effect/35VnW/9/)). However, you will notice that there are two commented out sections in the validation which provide the custom messages. If these are included, once there is a value in any one of the referenced fields, the submit button will return an error.

"{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', ..."

As far as I can see, the syntax is correct and method is the right one. Can anybody see where I have gone wrong?

(I realise that I can get round the problem in other ways by creating data-msg-required="??xx??" attributes for each element, but that's a bit inelegant and long-winded.)

Any ideas please?

[Here is another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4effect/pdn5a/) showing the form with only one set of options. The custom messages for the price field have been enabled, however, if the custom messages for the name field are uncommented, the validation will crash on submit.

Comment: Why not try version 1.11.1 instead of 1.11.0pre?  I also think you need to remove that `.on('submit')` handler.  You don't need it when you already have `submitHandler` built into the plugin.

Comment: @Sparky, your observation about the version was spot on! By using version 1.11.1 the submit error has been solved. The issue with the custom messages is also solved for the first instance (with the iprice class). But with the conditional (.iname) class they were simply being ignored. However I realised that I can simply set a message for 'required' and as required is conditional, the message will be too. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/e4effect/PbXJf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your plugin to the latest version.  (1.11.1)